# Fastest way to send serial commands and do something

Tags: serial, esp8266

I am trying to send a lot of serial commands really fast. I basically need to change color of my LED strip many times per second (10 times per second should really be enough). If I do this over WiFi, it will eventually clutter up and make the ESP8266 unresponsive. I need to send the colors as hex, then convert them into usable values (HEX to RGB). Something tells me that's going to cost a lot of resources and the MCU is therefore spending a lot of time just converting the colors into RGB values. Here's a pseudo code example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
void loop() {
    if(Serial.available()) {
        if(Serial.read().first(8) == "0xABCDEF") {
            //0xABCDEF is basically my indicator saying "this is for individual LEDs"
            //Serial.read() can now be something like 0xABCDEF FF0000 00FF00 0000FF FFFFFF 000000
            char* colors[] = Serial.read().split(" ");
            colorLED(colors);

        }
    }
}

void colorLED(colors) {
    for(i = 1; i < colors.length; i++) {
        strip.SetPixelColor(i, color[i]);
    }
}
```

I hope this example makes sense. I can send a serial command like `0xABCDEF FF0000 00FF00 0000FF FFFFFF 000000`. 5 colors in HEX.

My real question is: How do I take a lot of inputs like above (or another way) and turn them into strings, so I can convert them to RGB? Is there a better way to send commands (like pure RGB values? but remember I need to send many)?. Here is how I convert my colors into RGB:

```
//hexColor can be "FF0000"
int number = (int)strtol(&hexColor[0], NULL, 16);

int r = number >> 16;
int g = number >> 8 & 0xFF;
int b = number & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: don't.

Don't even consider strings in any form. Instead you want a state machine.

In pseudocode:

1. Start with an invalid count number (-1)
2. Read a character.
3. If that character is `x` then set your counter to 0.
4. Otherwise, if counter is 0 or more, convert the character to a number and place it into the right byte depending on the value of your counter
5. Increment counter
6. If counter is 6 then set your LED colours and set the counter to "invalid".
7. Return to start.

Or, in untested C:

```
static int8_t counter = -1;
static uint8_t r = 0;
static uint8_t g = 0;
static uint8_t b = 0;

if (Serial.available()) {
    char c = Serial.read();
    if (c == 'x') {
        counter = 0;
    } else {
        if (c > 0x39) c -= 7;
        uint8_t v = c & 0x0f;
        switch (counter) {
            case 0: r = v << 4; break;
            case 1: r |= v;
            case 2: g = v << 4; break;
            case 3: g |= v;
            case 4: b = v << 4; break;
            case 5: b |= v;
        }
        counter++;
        if (counter == 6) {
            counter = -1;
            analogWrite(3, r);
            analogWrite(5, g);
            analogWrite(6, b);
        }
    }
}
```

The "clever" bit that may confuse you is:

```
if (c > 0x39) c -= 7;
uint8_t v = c & 0x0f;
```

That is, if the character is greater than a "9" (character 0x39) then it *should* be a-f. Subtracting 7 from it converts ASCII HEX from `0123456789ABCDEF` to `0123456789:;<=>?`.  If you then mask it with 0x0F you end up with a number between 0 and 15, or 0-F in hex.

The rest just takes each nibble and places it into the right half of the right colour variable.

Comment: Damn, I see that is pretty freaking fast! Immediately when I send the command, it's being sent to the serial monitor (even using `Serial.println()` which I assume is somewhat "slow"). That works pretty damn well! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Sorry for hijacking this, but while I have an experienced person here: I use Makuna's NeoPixel library. This requires me to set my LED strip to the RX on the ESP8266. I currently use the `NeoEsp8266Dma800KbpsMethod` method, [which you can read more about here](https://github.com/Makuna/NeoPixelBus/wiki/NeoPixelBus-object), and this means `Serial.read()` will be unavailable (as far as I understand). Do you happen to know if there is an alternative? I did try all the other ones, but unfortunately none of them worked. I think I need to hook it up to another pin, so RX/TX is free (at least RX is)

Comment: I don't know what is available for the ESP8266. There is probably a software serial implementation, but I don't like them much, they tend to mess with interrupts and block things from happening. Better would be if you could use some other communication protocol, such as I2C, to get the data in.

Comment: I probably could, but it all depends on the NeoPixel library I'm using. Can you skim that page really quick and see if I can use any of the other ones, and if it's only a question of specifying the right pin and using another method/bus (and also hook up the LED strip data pin to that pin).

Comment: I actually got it to work with NeoEsp8266Uart800KbpsMethod and GPIO02 (D4). Holy freaking hell it's fast now!

Comment: Note that you don't need to break the data into R, G and B, as the Neopixel library has an overloaded `setPixelColor(uint16_t pixelIndex, uint32_t color)` with the color given as `0x00RRGGBB`. The `switch` can then be replaced by `color = (color << 4) | v;`

Comment: @EdgarBonet Indeed. Another method, if you do want separate RGB values is to shift the nibbles into a union with a 32-bit integer overlay divided into a 4 byte struct.

Comment: You could get a 50% reduction in serial data by sending the raw binary values rather than as hex. e.g. for each pixel send 4 binary bytes rather than sending 6 bytes of ascii. Less data sent and less decoding = faster code. Decoding becomes as simple as `uint8_t r = Serial.read();` Why 4 bytes rather than 3? Because that way the data lines up nicely if you to use a uint32_t at one end or the other (stick to uint8_t's on 8 or 16 bit MCUs but on an ARM part or if a PC is sending the data then this is worth it) and you can then use the top (unused) byte as a start of data marker.

Comment: @Andrew Sending binary data is much more tricky than you are suggesting. A single "start of data" byte, when you're working with 8-bit data, is not practical - how do you distinguish it from data? Instead you would need proper packets with data escaping and such - and for such a small amount of data you would end up with a packet only fractionally smaller than (if not bigger than) the 7 bytes of ASCII representation.

Comment: @Majenko Sorry, I wasn't clear, I didn't mean an 8 bit start marker, I meant a 32 bit message where that byte was also set could act as a start marker. e.g. 0x01010101. If you look for 4 or more non-zero bytes in a row then you know that the next 0 byte will always be the first (always 0) byte of color data.

Comment: @Andrew And if you don't have 4 or more non-zero bytes in a row? Synchronisation is not possible with just one byte when that byte may appear in the data. You need at least 2 bytes for the synchronisation in a specific pattern. Then you need an "escape" byte in the data stream to prevent that pattern from ever appearing in the data, and of course escaping of that escape byte to prevent it being interpreted as an escape byte. Take a look at some existing binary protocols, such as telnet's IAC system, for examples.

Comment: @Majenko "Synchronisation is not possible with just one byte when that byte may appear in the data. You need at least 2 bytes for the synchronisation in a specific pattern." Correct. Hence the 32 bit start marker where none of the values are 0. If you don't have 4 non-zeros in a row the you have connected in the middle of a message and must wait for the next start marker, exactly the same as with ascii.

Comment: @Andrew Ah, right, got you now. So you would want to re-synchronise periodically to make sure no bytes have been lost - so efficiency depends on how often you want / need to re-sync. You wouldn't want to leave it too long between syncs in case you missed the very first one, and an initial sync never happened. You'd then discard a large number of packets until the next sync - so getting the balance right would be important. Adds a lot of complexity to think about to save a couple of bytes per packet.

Comment: @Majenko He's talking about an LED strip with different colours per LED so presumably WS2812 parts. It would be logical to resync at the start of each refresh, exactly how he was doing it in the initial question using ASCII but missing from your solution.

Comment: @Andrew Ah, so make the whole stop worth a packet, with a header of, say, 0x5555AAAA. That would work for this specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

Since Majenko is convinced that using binary is far too complicated here's how to do it in binary sending 32 bits per color.
The start of strip marker is any 4 non-zero bytes in a row e.g 0x01010101
Each LED is then sent as four binary bytes: 0x00, 0xRR, 0xGG, 0xBB

In the unlikely event that a byte is lost in transmission then it will re-sync at the start of the next update, depending upon the pattern there is a fair chance that lost data will be noticed and the incorrect colors not get displayed on the strip.

```
loop() {    
  static color_t color; 
  static int8_t counter = -1;
  static int ledIndex = 0;
  static bool aligned= false;

  if (Serial.available()) {
    if (aligned) {
    switch (counter) {
      case 0: color.r=Serial.read(); break;
      case 1: color.g=Serial.read(); break;
      case 2: color.b=Serial.read(); 
              strip.SetPixelColor(ledIndex, color);
              ledIndex++;
              break;
      case 3: // first byte of next data, should always be 0
              // only not 0 if we've lost a byte or want to restart the strip
              if (Serial.read() != 0) {
                aligned=false;
                counter = 0;
              } else 
                counter = -1;
              break;
      default: break;
    }
    counter++;
  } else { // not aligned
    ledIndex = 0;
    if (Serial.read() != 0) // count non-zeros
      counter++;
    else {                  
      if (counter >= 4)     // had a start marker, next byte is r
        aligned = true;
      counter = 0;          
    }
  }
}
```

Is it worth doing it in binary? It gives a 50% decrease in RS232 data which if serial data rate is an issue will be a big help. It also gives a decrease in required calculations, if you look at the code there are virtually no mathematical operations beyond increasing counters.
Personally I prefer this method because it just seems more efficient and cleaner to transfer numbers as numbers rather than converting them to text and back but ultimately if you don't need every last bit of performance then it comes down to what you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: So far what I have counted using a high FPS camera, I can easily track 20+ updates a second using Majenko's code. I think that's very, very good considering I won't ever need to do that.

Comment: I would hope so, twenty updates a second isn't that fast unless you have a very long chain of LEDs. If you code it right the RS 232 should be the slowest part of the system and you should easily be able to get 20 FPS on chains of several hundred LEDs. As I indicated, binary gives you that little bit more if you need it, if you don't need it then it's simply an alternative approach.